# spark-submit reding MINIO fails no credentials found but they are in spark-defaults.conf

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, minio

I've been debugging this for hours and I have failed so far.

I have a stand-alone spark cluster and a Minio server with docker compose. I did it based on "Adding some MinIO to your standalone Apache Spark cluster by Vasileios Anagnostopoulos."

I have had a whole different experience so far compared to what he had in that article.
after figthing with different bugs now I got one last problem, the spark cluster does not access the credentials!

- I am running it locally I am not using an ec2 instance.
- I know AWS looks for the credentials in .AWS/credentials the java system properties and environment variables.
- As I am not using an ec2 instance I opted for the environment variables.
- I have AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=theroot AND AWS_SECRET_ACCES_KEY=theroot123 in my docker-compose file for the master and worker node.
- I have checked inside the containers and i do have the enviroment variables set.
- I am coping my custom spark-defaults.conf to my container conf folder, the conf file looks like this:

  spark.ui.reverseProxy true

  spark.hadoop.mapreduce.outputcommitter.factory.scheme.s3a org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.S3ACommitterFactory

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name directory

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.tmp.path /tmp/spark_staging

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.buffer.dir /tmp/spark_local_buf

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode fail

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key theroot

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key theroot123

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint http://my-minio-server:9000

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled false

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access true

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem

  spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.attempts.maximum 0

spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4 --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 spark-access-minio.py
```

Errors log:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
    
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
    
    java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://mybucket/addresses.csv: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making it work like this. but still I want to know how to set up in the conf file.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Test json")\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://my-minio-server:9000")\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", 'theroot')\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", 'theroot123')\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", True)\
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")\
    .getOrCreate()
    
    

log4jLogger = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)

sourceBucket = "mybucket"

inputPath = f"s3a://{sourceBucket}/addresses.csv"
outputPath = f"s3a://{sourceBucket}/output_survey4.csv"
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").format("s3selectCSV").csv(inputPath)
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(outputPath)
spark.stop()
```

Comment: Hi, if this is an update to your question, add it there. You can edit your question. Here it will be lost.